# how to deal with integers and flip them

Tags: java, int

haw can i flip an integer at a certain index
for example i have this number 1001 and i need to flip it starting from index 2
the result is going to be 1010
here is what i  tried any easier ways?

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int code = scan.nextInt();
        int index = scan.nextInt();
        String s = code + "";
        String f = "";

        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= index; i--) {
            f += s.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            f += s.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Another question is that haw i shift every digit to the left  for example if i have 1001 it will become 1100

Comment: try bit operations defined in java

Comment: (a) Are you supposed to be working with decimal integers (1001 is a thousand and one) or with binary numbers (1001 is 9)? (b) Define your "flip" better. What happens when I flip "12345" from index 1, for example?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I AM supposed to be working in decimal integers and i mean by flip is that at this index i flip the number from right to left for example 12345 fliped at index 1 will become 54321

Comment: Wait, your indexes start from zero (Flip at 2 is 1001→1010) or from 1 (Flip at 1  is 12345 → 54321)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `reverse()` method of the `StringBuilder` class to reverse the number and then parse it back as an integer. Use the StringBuilder as follows:

```
    StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder("1234");
    num.reverse(); // is now "4321"
```

To parse the integer:

```
    int i = Integer.parseInt(num.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. This assumes you are using a 0-indexed system for choosing where the reversal starts.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int code = scan.nextInt();
int index = scan.nextInt();
String s = code + "";
String f = s.substring(0, index);
    for(int i = index; i < s.length(); i++)
        f += s.charAt(s.length() - (i - index) - 1);
System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `flip` operation if I assume that you mean that a string such as `12345` consists of indices `[1,2,3,4,5]` rather than `[0,1,2,3,4]`˙ and starting from index of `1` is inclusive flip from `1` to `5`, and your operation goes from left to right, then you can do the following

```
    int index = 1;
    String number = "12345";
    String subnumber = number.substring(index - 1); //first index, 0th character
    String reversedNumber = new StringBuilder(subnumber).reverse().toString();
    String result = number.substring(0, index - 1) + reversedNumber;
    System.out.println(result); //54321
```

Of course, if it was supposed to from right to left, then you need to mess with the length of the String and mirror the operations...

Comment: Why do you create all these Strings? They will just float around in the String pool. Just use a StringBuilder. It can also do substring and is much more efficient.

Comment: @ling_jan it simplified the indexing issues.